# NIC network circuit with grounded output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, network, negative-resistance

My class was given a series of circuit networks to calculate the transmission of the system. One of those networks is this type of Negative Impedance Converter with the common ground output.
How can I get the matrices [Z, Y, T]?

[image]